# Spring JSON converter. How to bind different types

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have an ajax call with data: "{"timeLeft": 12:33, "cheked": true}". On the clienside timeleft format: HH:MM, but on the serverside we need to convert it to milliseconds (Long). How to do that with MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter?
In Spring after submitting form we can use PropertyEditors. Is there something similar for json data in Jackson Converters? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` uses Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to deserialize from JSON to Pojos (or from JSON to Maps/JsonNodes). So, one approach is to create a POJO that is to be the deserialized object.

If the expected time value is truly "HH:MM" where "HH" actually means a "Hour of Day (0-23)" and "MM" means "Minute of Hour (0-59)" then the following approach can be used.

Add a custom `@JsonCreator` to your backing POJO:

```
public class TimeLeftPojo {
    // The time pattern
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

    // The checked property
    private final boolean checked;

    // The parsed time
    private final LocalTime timeLeft;

    // A creator that takes the string "HH:mm" as arg
    @JsonCreator
    public static TimeLeftPojo of(
            @JsonProperty("timeLeft") String timeLeft, 
            @JsonProperty("checked") boolean checked) {

        return new TimeLeftPojo(
                LocalTime.parse(timeLeft, formatter), checked);
    }

    public TimeLeftPojo(final LocalTime timeLeft, final boolean checked) {
        this.timeLeft = timeLeft;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public LocalTime getTimeLeft() {
        return timeLeft;
    }

    public long toMillisecondOfDay() {
        return getTimeLeft().toSecondOfDay() *  1000;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
}
```

Then the deserialization works out of the box:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Changed the spelling from "cheked" to "checked"
String json = "{\"timeLeft\": \"10:00\", \"checked\": true}";
final TimeLeftPojo timeLeftPojo = mapper.readValue(json, TimeLeftPojo.class);
System.out.println(timeLeftPojo.toMillisecondOfDay());
```

The output will be:

> 36000000

The JavaDoc for `@JsonCreator` can [be found here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html).

Note that the time pattern is "HH:mm", not "HH:MM" as in the original query ("M" is month, not minute).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any object on server side where you map this json? Perhaps you can use an implementation of JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer for this field and convert the time into a timestamp.